# Might HSM add a flagging option for migrating posts to EL&U?

Tags: feature-request, migration, flagging

A  few recent questions, such as [this one](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5592/how-to-understand-the-context-below), do not appear to be about mathematics, science, or their history. They seem to stem more from someone's misunderstanding of archaic language usage (or even "facetious" if I interpret the linked example correctly).

Currently, the best we can do is flag the question as off-topc or "unclear what you're asking". But in cases like this, it might be better to migrate the question to English Language and Usage (or even ELL). The only option currently in the menu for "belongs on another site on this network" (Flagging>Closing>Off-Topic>Migration) is for this meta.

So, might it be possible to add EL&U to that list?

Answer (score 2):

Adding migration paths has to be done by SE staff, but there are several reasons why this probably wouldn't work very well. First, migration paths are almost never added for beta sites. One reason is that the volume of questions we'd want to migrate is actually quite small. SE staff would want to see double-digit numbers of questions migrated to EL&U per month before they'd consider adding such a path. Presently we've never migrated a question to either EL&U or ELL. Without any history or demand for such an option, using a custom "needs moderator intervention" flag describing where it should be migrated is pretty clearly the better option. Only when moderators are overwhelmed by the number of questions for migration do migration paths make sense, and presently that isn't the case at all.

Secondly, the standard SE policy is that we should only migrate good questions which are off-topic here. Migrating bad questions creates more work for the target site with no benefit. It isn't clear to me that the question you've linked would be a good question on EL&U. In particular that post actually asks several questions. In addition it does not really make any sense without context from the link. I'm not a regular user on EL&U but I'd be surprised if this question would fly there. So I think the better option for this question is just to close it here (which I've done). The user can re-ask the question at EL&U without too much difficulty themselves if they agree it belongs there.

Comment: Perhaps moderators have extra buttons but as I stated, there is no way for me to flag "belongs on another site" except to this meta. So the best I can do is flag a question I think might work better somewhere else as " in need of moderator attention". Is there some other general explanation about how this flag turns into a "migration path" ?

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken about which flag you should use (it's been a while since I've done this myself). A custom "In need of moderator intervention" flag describing where you think the question should be migrated to is the right approach. Keep in mind that we probably won't migrate questions unless they're clearly off-topic here and seem to be a good fit for the target site; otherwise we'd rather the OP take the effort to re-ask the question on that site.

Comment: Yep, this is basically the network-wide policy (nice explanation, Logan!). For some additional info, HSM hasn't migrated a single post to either English site since at least March 2015 (which happened to be a convenient date to look up). In fact, in that timespan, only 13 posts were migrated out to any destination at all.